# Referencing Yii form variables inside a Javascript function using jQuery

Tags: yii

I have a Yii CActiveForm backed with a CFormModel and I'm using the onChange htmlOption to call the javascript send().
The send function tweeks some of the form variables and populates a hidden field ready for form serialising and POSTing back to the server.

My problem is that I don't know how to reference the form fields from inside the javascript function using jQuery because the CActiveForm changes their names. Currently I'm having to hard code the names eg `$('#SearchForm_myvar').val("myval");` which doesn't seem right.
How can I reference the form variables inside the javascript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer from the source so putting it here in case someone else wants it.
The jQuery id is:

```
"#" . CHtml::activeId($model,'myvar')
```